# Java is not working with netbeans IDE 7 on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, netbeans-7, ubuntu-11.10

I am using Netbeans IDE 7.1.1 on ubuntu 11.10, when I try to create JAVA project using File-> New Project-> JAVA Project-> JAVA Application, it shows me the following error:

> The JDK is missing an required to run some NetBeans modules. Please use the --jdkhome command line option to specify a JDK installation or see http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre for more information.

So I used the following command

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and the result was:

```
    Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
    0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java        1061      auto mode
    1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java        1061      manual mode
  * 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
```

I tried to run through terminal using the following command:

```
netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```

but I got error:

```
Cannot find java. Please use the --jdkhome switch.
```

and netbeans doesn't start as well.

I tried this command using every path which I found through this command also:

```
whereis java
```

but every time I got the same error and netbeans doesn't start.

in netbeans config file (`/usr/local/netbeans-7.0/etc/netbeans.conf`) jdkhome path is :

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre"
```

when I tried to run netbeans using this path through this command:

```
netbeans --jdkhome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
```

netbeans runs but when try to create project the same JDK missing error is displayed.

One interesting thing also I encountered, if I use Eclipse every thing goes fine, I am able to create projects in eclipse and programs  run smoothly.
Eclipse doesn't show any wanning or errors like JDK is missing.

Comment: Have you tried Oracle's JDK for Java 7?

Comment: no I am just using default openJDK installed through ubuntu's software center. I haven't tried installing JDK from oracle, because I was in doubt whether or not two versions on same system will work properly.

Comment: For me everything went okay with NB 7.1, 7.1.1 and Ub 12.04. Nothing extra to do. Maybe do update-alternatives 2, uninstall NB and reinstall. netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0" without jre.

Comment: Netbeans works fine with OpenJDK. That shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It sounds like it should work the way you have it. Also you can have any number of versions/copies of Java installed at once and have it work.

Comment: just an addition for FreeBSD9.1 and NB7.3:
edit <netbeans-7.3_installdir>/etc/netbeans.conf to include line
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/local/openjdk7"
with "--jdkhome ..." I had no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Netbeans 7.1 on Ubuntu 11.10 and it works great, I didn't need to specify anything extra to get the JDK working.  Here is my `update-alternatives`:

```
Selection    Path                                      Priority   Status
 ------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode
```

How did you install Netbeans 7.1?  As far as I remember it is not in the repositories.  I used the GUI Swing installer from the Netbeans website.  I installed it as a *user* not using `sudo` or `su`.

Also check how you *run* Netbeans, try going to `NETBEANS/bin` folder and running `./netbeans`.

Comment: I downloaded Netbeans 7 (all) version and installed it through terminal using: sudo sh netbeans.sh

Comment: On, I installed as a _user_, not as root.  So, instead try `sh neatbeans.sh`

Comment: Since you installed using sudo, you probably have a permissions issue.  Netbeans cannot write some configurations and it is breaking.

Comment: OK I will try reinstalling it

Comment: Using sudo create pb with some module but it doesn't affect Java. I made it with version 7.0. Every time I run Netbeans I get cacert warnings about glassfish but all works fine.

Comment: Wow!! re-installation without sudo worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[@Vipin Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180290/vipin-kumar)

Hi Vinay,
I have come across the solution which will work on any version of Ubuntu definitely keeping other java versions intact.

For this, please download tar.gz version of Java from 
[Oracle website.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

1. Suppose, your jdk installation tar file at location `/home/don/`
2. don@ubuntu ~ $ `tar zxf jdk-7u45-linux-i586.tar.gz`
3. don@ubuntu ~ $ `sudo bash`

   [sudo] password for don:
4. ubuntu ~ # `mv /home/don/jdk1.7.0_45/ /usr/lib/jvm/`
5. ubuntu ~ # `cd /usr/lib/jvm/`
6. ubuntu jvm # `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java 3`
7. ubuntu jvm # `update-alternatives --config java`

> ```
>  Selection    Path                                           Priority   Status  
> ------------------------------------------------------------  
> * 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode  
>   1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode  
>   2            /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java               3         manual mode  
> Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
> update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
> ```

8. ubuntu jvm # `java -version`
   java version "1.7.0_45"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

Done !!

Now, the turn of netbeans.

I assumed your file is saved at location /home/don.

On netbeans installation file, right click -> `properties` -> `permissions` -> `Allow executing file as a program` under Execute attribute.

Now click on installer, select run when asks for action and your installation will start without any hassles.

Happy programming !!